# How many styles of chanting Shukla Yajurveda are there?

Tags: vedas, yajur-veda, vedic-chanting, shukla-yajurveda

How many styles of chanting Shukla Yajurveda are there? I have heard shukla yajurveda chanting in two different styles, what are they?